# Calculate size of file using Dropbox API for iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, filesize

How do I find the size of a file using Dropbox API? I have been able to download the file, place it into NSData and calculate its file size, but that is too memory intensive. I only want to download the image if the file size is greater than 500kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET request to

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/<path>
```

Will return metadata including the file-size!

As described at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata
And https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata-details

Make a request there first, and if the size is too large, don't make the subsequent GET to /files/

**EDIT :**
To answer your comment, I looked through the iOS SDK (which unfortunately lacks documentation) and found a method in DBRestClient.h that should help you:

```
- (void)loadMetadata:(NSString*)path;
```

Hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction. There are a few other methods that may be of use to you, and I imagine you will interact with the DBMetadata object as well. Look through the (open-source) SDK and you should be able to find the data you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a way that I can do this using the Dropbox SDK for iOS?

Comment: Edited my answer to try and help you find an SDK-provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the SDK and found a long defined in DBMetadata.h called `totalBytes` which appears to solve my problem.

Comment: I think this return nil on response, Are you getting size ?